# IE-8 Iframe page redirection issue after form submission

Tags: iframe, redirect

I have one php page form.php. Once user fill out form and click on 'Submit' all data is saved in database and he is redirected to list.php.

Now i have added form.php in iframe of another site.
The problem is in IE-8. In iframe once user submit data, data is saved in database but user is not redirected to list.php but user.php page is refreshed with blank form.

It's working in IE-Tester and IE-8 mode of IE developer toolbar, But not in IE-8.

Comment: have you upload that anywhere ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing something in your question.

There might be some cookie issue.

Add below code in your header file and check

```
header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
```

Thanks

Comment: I added this in response header, but still doesn't work, what's problem?